# Searching for upload finds reload.png

Tags: resharper, visual-studio-2019, resharper-2019

When I - in Visual studio, Resharper Ultimate - press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+T, I expected to be able to search for a type.

However, it seems to be the file search dialog.

When I write "upload", one search hit is `reload.png`.

Can I do any of the following?

1. Search for types
2. Disable fuzzy search hits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can search for types, just add a "/":
[image]

AFAIK you cannot change the behaviour of Search Everywhere, however, If you need a more specific search you can use ReSharper > Find > Search with Pattern.